# Qt creator: "Ctrl-click" and "Find usage" function

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have been using Qt creator 4.0.2 with Qt 5.2. I have started to encounter a
problem that, when I Ctrl+click on a function definition, it should navigate me to function declaration and vice versa. But it does not seem to work, and the cursor is taken to some other place in the function. Also, when I try to use the function "Find usage" of a certain function, it does not show all
the usages of functions. Instead show some other places, where these functions are not used. I encounter this problem only in the file on which I have been working recently, it works fine in other files.

Secondly, When I am writing the code, sometimes for the same variable it shows different colors (Shown in attached file).

[image: Image with different color for variables]

Lastly, I have been seeing some strange variable selections. I don't know
what these are. You can find the screenshot in attachment.

[image: Image with variable selections]

Anybody has encountered the same problem or can tell me how can I fix these issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Tools >> C++ >> Reparse Externally Changed Files`.

Comment: Nope, it did not work.

Comment: Nobody ever encountered this problem ?